# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

1) I installed mysql;

2) I changed `bin-addres` row from 127.0.0.1 to my server IP

3) I changed root permission with `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` this line returns `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

4) I launched `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';` returns `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '******' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 1000`

When I tried to connect to my db with hibernate, the system returns me `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

What have I to do?

(Ps. I'm sorry for bad english).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523324/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow full access to database from any ip OR replace `%` with your IP from where do you want to access database and try.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
```

Comment: thanks, with MySql Workbench the problem is fixed, but hibernate returns the same error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Now grant permission to user from this domain. net-130-25-42-18.cust.vodafonedsl.it

Answer (score 0):

This is hibernate code, the error is:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'net-130-25-42-18.cust.vodafonedsl.it' (using password: YES)
```

I don't know why instead of localhost there is 'net-130-25-42-18.cust.vodafonedsl.it'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://luxury:3306/newdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Pass123</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Mapped classes -->
        <mapping resource="applica/newdb/domain/model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="applica/newdb/domain/model/Role.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: As per your commnet `with MySql Workbench the problem is fixed,` its working with mysql tool. So, there is some issue with your code so please make sure you are using correct user and password and host name as in workbench.

Comment: Problem solved, when I used GRANT ALL I didn't used identified by 'password' so connection don't need password

Answer (score 0):

Change your database connection url

```
jdbc:mysql://your_database_server_domain_or_ip:3306/newdb
```

i.e.

```
jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/newdb
```

Comment: luxury represents my server IP in the hosts file.

Comment: Try once with server ip instead of domain

Comment: with server IP java returns this error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure